# Operation timed out when attempting ssh host computer

Tags: networking, mac, ssh, unix

Cant ssh into host apple computer & cant ping

- I can screen share host via ARD
- I can ssh other computers from my remote computer
- I can copy files to host via ARD
- ssh computer's from host
- host computer running apple firewall, allowing incoming connections for remote login and remote management

Attempt samples

1) `$ ssh user@host.ip.blah` Hangs with error message:

```
ssh: connect to host host.ip.blah port 22: Operation timed out
```

2) `$ ssh -p 2222 user@host.ip.blah` Hangs with error message:

```
ssh: connect to host host.ip.blah port 2222: Operation timed out
```

3) `$ ssh -vvv 2222 user@host.ip.blah` Console output:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to user@host.ip.blah port 22.
ssh: connect to host user@host.ip.blah port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: So what port have you configured ssh to run on, the port configuration in that file, is commented out

Comment: I have not configured anything, I usually just use the default port to ssh to computer.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall is not blocking your connections...?